# Form Value Relation Dropdowns in QField

Tags: qgis, qfield

**I created form-value related dropdowns in a QGIS project** that work perfectly. The Idea is to collect data of points in the field. All types ("Art") have subtypes ("Subart") that are dependant on their type.

Here some examples: [image][image][image]

**As I opened the project in QField, the dropdowns were blocked.** Is QField not capable to handle related dropdowns?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, for now you can't filter a dropdown based on another field value (if you really need it you'll have to develop it yourself or sponsor a development...).

One workaround is to use one subtype field for each type and using both conditional visibility to hide those that doesn't correspond to the selected type and expression-based default value to auto fill them to "non applicable". Then you could create another hidden field with an expression that synthetise all subtype field.
That's a messy workaround that made you add lot's of field (in your case 9) but it's the only one I was able to find to facilitate accurate field update...

Answer (score 0):

It will be possible to use the function current__value() in the 3.30 version of Qgis : [Changelog](https://changelog.qgis.org/en/qgis/version/3.30/#feature-data-defined-form-widget-editable-state)