# QGIS & Qfield value map based on another field value

Tags: qfield

I am working with the latest QGIS ( LTR) & Qfield.

What I am trying to figure out is how to get value map widgets to be a mandatory requirement base on the value map selection of another field.

Here's an example: I have a field value map that has 8 items, when you pick a specific one I want the value map widget constraint to be mandatory, but only on that one.

If I were to 'culvert' in the first value map widget, then I want the other field with a value map of length's ( an assorted 6 lengths) to be mandatory and yet one more field value map like 'material' aka plastic or steel to also be mandatory.

So when it's working, if the persons pick culvert, then they are forced to pick the type of culvert ( steel or plastic) and the length as well, otherwise the data can't be saved.

Comment: maybe this is part of your answer? https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/341849/form-value-relation-dropdowns-in-qfield?rq=1